# React Native - UseEffect and other functions takes time to load

Tags: reactjs, react-native, function, react-hooks

I am using React Native to create an app. My useEffect and other functions takes around a minute to call which caused delay and reduce user experience.

```
 useEffect(() => {
const token = JWTToken('');

 getAllChannels(token);
 }, [navigation]);
```

// code to add channel

```
const clickSave = () => {
const token = JWTToken('');

addchannel(token);
};
```

// Render code

```
return (
<KeyboardAvoidingView
  style={{
    display: 'flex',
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  }}
  behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}>
  <SafeAreaView
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: !darkTheme
        ? Colors.light.f2Color
        : Colors.dark.backgrounColor,
    }}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={goBack}>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          marginHorizontal: width * 0.02,
          marginVertical: height * 0.02,
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <SvgLeftArrow
          color={!darkTheme ? Colors.light.textColor : Colors.light.white}
        />

        <Text
          style={{
            fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Bold',
            fontSize: 20,
            color: !darkTheme ? Colors.light.textColor : Colors.light.white,
            marginLeft: width * 0.03,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          }}>
          Manage Channels
        </Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <View
      style={{
        width: width * 0.95,
        height: Platform.OS === 'android' ? height * 0.06 : height * 0.05,
        marginVertical: height * 0.01,
        backgroundColor: !darkTheme
          ? Colors.light.white
          : Colors.dark.changePwdText,
        marginHorizontal: Platform.OS === 'android' && height * 0.01,
        borderRadius: 13,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}>
      <TextInput
        style={{
          fontSize: 16,
          fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
          paddingHorizontal: width * 0.04,
          color: !darkTheme
            ? Colors.light.textColor
            : Colors.dark.textColor,
          width: width * 0.86,
        }}
        value={searchChannel}
        onChangeText={value => {
          setSearchChannel(value);
        }}
        clearButtonMode="always"
        secureTextEntry={false}
        placeholder="Add a channel..."
        placeholderTextColor={
          !darkTheme ? Colors.light.placeholderColor : Colors.dark.textColor
        }
      />

      {!createLoader ? (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={clickSave}>
          <Image
            source={require('../assets/images/black-round-tick.png')}
            resizeMode="contain"
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ) : (
        <ActivityIndicator color={Colors.light.black} />
      )}
    </View>

    {!loader ? (
      <FlatList
        data={channelList}
        scrollEnabled={true}
        renderItem={({item, index}) =>
          channelList.length > 0 ? (
            <ChannelComponent
              item={item}
              setCallGetChannel={setCallGetChannel}
            />
          ) : (
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                alignSelf: 'center',
              }}>
              <Text>No Channels Found!</Text>
            </View>
          )
        }
        numColumns={1}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          alignSelf: 'center',
          flex: 1,
        }}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0}
        bounces={false}
        style={{marginBottom: height * 0.05}}
      />
    ) : (
      <View
        style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <ActivityIndicator color={Colors.light.black} />
      </View>
    )}
  </SafeAreaView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
);
```

I have created as above but each function takes time to call. Even Loader shows after a minute. This is happening in my complete code. Even TouchableOpacity is also taking multiple attempts to perform.

Please suggest if you have answer for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have infinity loop here:

```js
useEffect(() => {
 const token = JWTToken('');
 getAllChannels(token);
}, [navigation]);
```

You need to control your effect more precisely. For example, you can add condition inside your effect like:

```js
useEffect(() => {
 if (!isLoading) {
   const token = JWTToken('');
   getAllChannels(token);
 }
}, [isLoading]);
```

Another way is to check how many rerenders do you have with this plugin https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render or with Flipper